# how to get values from report corresponding to check boxes which are checked in oracle apex

Tags: oracle-apex

After getting report by sql commands in apex, I want to store data of variables `sid,serial#` corresponding to check boxes which are checked. After that I have to execute alter system kill session `'sid,serial#'` in apex itself

Answer (score 0):

Hi there I'll show you the approach used by [skillbuilders](http://skillbuilders.com/) on [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fXxhoEQb6bA) tutorial, which is based on [collections](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2012/12-jul/o42plsql-1653077.html)

The approach consist on four steps, the idea is to make a report over a collection rather than from a set of tables. I'll make a description of all steps but I strongly suggest that you see the video on the link above for specific details on the code.

**First** you need to create the collection (**and named it**) with the information that you
   want to show on your report, for this you will make a string with the query itself and then bind the variables that you may (or may not) need. Here's a template for your collection, keep in mind that this template needs to be adjusted to your scenario. **In your case what interest you the most will be the items #47 and #50, this are a status field (47) and a check box field(50).**

```
DECLARE

   l_collection_name APEX_COLLECTIONS.COLLECTION_NAME%TYPE;
   l_bind_names      APEX_APPLICATION_GLOBAL.VC_ARR2;
   l_bind_values     APEX_APPLICATION_GLOBAL.VC_ARR2;
   l_query           VARCHAR2(32767);

BEGIN

   l_collection_name := 'REPLACE_NAME';

   IF apex_collection.collection_exists(l_collection_name)
   THEN
      apex_collection.delete_collection(
         p_collection_name => l_collection_name
      );
   END IF;

   --Query to initialize collection
   --Do not reorder columns later as that could break the values in the tabular form (reorder in report)
   l_query :=
         'SELECT col_1, ' --c001 => f01
      || '   col_2, ' --c002 => f02
      || '   col_3, ' --c003 => f03
      || '   col_4, ' --c004 => f04
      || '   col_5, ' --c005 => f05
      || '   NULL, ' --c006 => f06
      || '   NULL, ' --c007 => f07
      || '   NULL, ' --c008 => f08
      || '   NULL, ' --c009 => f09
      || '   NULL, ' --c010 => f10
      || '   NULL, ' --c011 => f11
      || '   NULL, ' --c012 => f12
      || '   NULL, ' --c013 => f13
      || '   NULL, ' --c014 => f14
      || '   NULL, ' --c015 => f15
      || '   NULL, ' --c016 => f16
      || '   NULL, ' --c017 => f17
      || '   NULL, ' --c018 => f18
      || '   NULL, ' --c019 => f19
      || '   NULL, ' --c020 => f20
      || '   NULL, ' --c021 => f21
      || '   NULL, ' --c022 => f22
      || '   NULL, ' --c023 => f23
      || '   NULL, ' --c024 => f24
      || '   NULL, ' --c025 => f25
      || '   NULL, ' --c026 => f26
      || '   NULL, ' --c027 => f27
      || '   NULL, ' --c028 => f28
      || '   NULL, ' --c029 => f29
      || '   NULL, ' --c030 => f30
      || '   NULL, ' --c031 => f31
      || '   NULL, ' --c032 => f32
      || '   NULL, ' --c033 => f33
      || '   NULL, ' --c034 => f34
      || '   NULL, ' --c035 => f35
      || '   NULL, ' --c036 => f36
      || '   NULL, ' --c037 => f37
      || '   NULL, ' --c038 => f38
      || '   NULL, ' --c039 => f39
      || '   NULL, ' --c040 => f40
      || '   NULL, ' --c041 => f41
      || '   NULL, ' --c042 => f42
      || '   NULL, ' --c043 => f43
      || '   NULL, ' --c044 => f44
      || '   NULL, ' --c045 => f45
      || '   NULL, ' --c046 => f46
      || '   ''O'', ' --c047 (for record status)
      || '   wwv_flow_item.md5(col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4, col_5) ' --c048 (for optimistic locking)
      --c049 for (not used in collection/reserevered for seq_id array)
      --c050 (not used in collection/reservered for delete checkbox array)
      || 'FROM some_table '
      || 'WHERE some_col = :PXX_ITEM_NAME';

   l_bind_names(1) := 'PXX_ITEM_NAME';  
   l_bind_values(1) := v('PXX_ITEM_NAME'); 

   apex_collection.create_collection_from_query_b(
      p_collection_name => l_collection_name,
      p_query           => l_query,
      p_names           => l_bind_names,
      p_values          => l_bind_values
   );

   IF :REQUEST = 'ADD'
   THEN
      apex_collection.add_member(
         p_collection_name => l_collection_name
      );
   END IF;

END;
```

**Step two** Once the collection has been successfully created you can make a report of it by querying directly to the collection, and by using the [APEX_ITEM](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37097_01/doc.42/e35127/apex_item.htm#AEAPI192) package you'll make this fields into proper items, notice that the fifth item is the checkbox linked to the 50th field on the collection. Once again, the code below it's just an example:

```
SELECT apex_item.hidden(47,c047,NULL,'f47_'|| '#ROWNUM#')
   || apex_item.hidden(48,c048,NULL,'f48_'|| '#ROWNUM#')
   || apex_item.hidden(49,seq_id,NULL,'f49_'|| '#ROWNUM#')
   || apex_item.hidden(1,c001,NULL,'f01_'|| '#ROWNUM#')
   || apex_item.checkbox(
      50, 
      seq_id,
      NULL,
      CASE 
         WHEN c047 = 'D' THEN seq_id
      END,
      ':',
      'f50_' || '#ROWNUM#'
   ) AS delete_checkbox,
   apex_item.text(
      2,
      c002,
      20,
      50,
      NULL,
      'f02_' || '#ROWNUM#'
   ) AS col_2,
   apex_item.text(
      3,
      c003,
      20,
      50,
      NULL,
      'f03_' || '#ROWNUM#'
   ) AS col_3,
   apex_item.select_list_from_lov_xl(
      4,
      NVL(c004, '-1'),
      'NAMED_LOV',
      NULL,
      'YES',
      '-1',
      '- Select Value -',
      'f04_' || '#ROWNUM#'
   ) AS col_4,
   apex_item.select_list_from_lov(
      5,
      NVL(c005, '-1'),
      'NAMED_LOV',
      NULL,
      'YES',
      '-1',
      '- Select Value -',
      'f05_' || '#ROWNUM#'
   ) AS col_5
FROM apex_collections
WHERE collection_name = 'REPLACE_NAME'
ORDER BY c003
```

**Step three** So, now you have a collection displaying items that could be modified in the page, but **will the changes be posted immediately into the collection?**...nope, you need to update the collection first, for that you have this code, here it's dealing with updates, row creation and row deletion.

```
DECLARE

   l_collection_name APEX_COLLECTIONS.COLLECTION_NAME%TYPE;
   l_original_md5    VARCHAR2(32);
   l_latest_md5      VARCHAR2(32);

BEGIN

   l_collection_name := 'REPLACE_NAME';

   FOR x IN 1 .. apex_application.g_f49.count 
   LOOP         
      IF apex_application.g_f01(x) IS NOT NULL --ID exists, check to see if record was updated
      THEN
         SELECT c048
         INTO l_original_md5
         FROM apex_collections
         WHERE collection_name = l_collection_name
            AND seq_id = apex_application.g_f49(x);

         l_latest_md5 := wwv_flow_item.md5(
            apex_application.g_f01(x),
            apex_application.g_f02(x),
            apex_application.g_f03(x),
            apex_application.g_f04(x),
            apex_application.g_f05(x)
         );

         IF l_original_md5 != l_latest_md5 
         THEN
            apex_collection.update_member(
               p_collection_name => l_collection_name,
               p_seq             => apex_application.g_f49(x),
               p_c001            => apex_application.g_f01(x),
               p_c002            => apex_application.g_f02(x),
               p_c003            => apex_application.g_f03(x),
               p_c004            => apex_application.g_f04(x),
               p_c005            => apex_application.g_f05(x),
               p_c047            => 'U',
               p_c048            => apex_application.g_f48(x)
            );
         END IF;
      ELSE --ID does not exist, must be new record
         apex_collection.update_member(
            p_collection_name => l_collection_name,
            p_seq             => apex_application.g_f49(x),
            p_c001            => apex_application.g_f01(x),
            p_c002            => apex_application.g_f02(x),
            p_c003            => apex_application.g_f03(x),
            p_c004            => apex_application.g_f04(x),
            p_c005            => apex_application.g_f05(x),
            p_c047            => 'N',
            p_c048            => apex_application.g_f48(x)
         );
      END IF;
   END LOOP;

   IF :REQUEST = 'DELETE' 
   THEN
      FOR x IN 1 .. apex_application.g_f50.count 
      LOOP
         apex_collection.update_member_attribute(
            p_collection_name => l_collection_name, 
            p_seq             => apex_application.g_f50(x), 
            p_attr_number     => '47', 
            p_attr_value      => 'D'
         );
      END LOOP;
   END IF;

END;
```

**Finally Step Four** Here we update the table/s based on the changes made to the collection. Using the 47th and 50th fields we know which ones should be updated, deleted, or created:

```
DECLARE

   l_table_md5       VARCHAR2(32);
   l_collection_name APEX_COLLECTIONS.COLLECTION_NAME%TYPE;
   l_del_count       PLS_INTEGER := 0;
   l_upd_count       PLS_INTEGER := 0;
   l_ins_count       PLS_INTEGER := 0;
   l_success_message VARCHAR2(32767);

   CURSOR op_lock_check_cur (
      p_id IN NUMBER
   )
   IS
      SELECT wwv_flow_item.md5(col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4, col_5)
      FROM some_table
      WHERE col_1 = op_lock_check_cur.p_id
      FOR UPDATE;

BEGIN

   l_collection_name := 'REPLACE_NAME';

   FOR x IN (
      SELECT *
      FROM apex_collections
      WHERE collection_name = l_collection_name
         AND c047 IN ('N','U','D')
   ) 
   LOOP
      IF x.c047 = 'N'
      THEN
         INSERT INTO some_table(
            col_1,
            col_2,            
            col_3, 
            col_4, 
            col_5
         ) VALUES (
            some_table_seq.nextval, 
            x.c002, 
            x.c003, 
            x.c004, 
            x.c005
         );

         l_ins_count := l_ins_count + 1;
      ELSIF x.c047 = 'U'
      THEN
         --Optimistic lock check
         --MD5 should be identical to collection initialization proc
         OPEN op_lock_check_cur(x.c001);
         FETCH op_lock_check_cur INTO l_table_md5;

         -- Compare the checksum values and if they are different, raise an error.
         IF l_table_md5 != x.c048 
         THEN
            raise_application_error( 
               -20001,
               'Current version of data in database has changed '
               || 'since user initiated update process.'
            );
         END IF;

         UPDATE some_table
         SET col_2 = x.c002,
            col_3 = x.c003,
            col_4 = x.c004,
            col_5 = x.c005
         WHERE CURRENT OF op_lock_check_cur;

         CLOSE op_lock_check_cur;

         l_upd_count := l_upd_count + 1;
      ELSIF x.c047 = 'D'
      THEN
         DELETE FROM some_table
         WHERE col_1 = x.c001;

         l_del_count := l_del_count + 1;
      END IF;
   END LOOP;

   apex_collection.delete_collection(p_collection_name => l_collection_name);

   l_success_message :=  
      l_ins_count || ' rows inserted, ' ||
      l_upd_count || ' rows updated, ' ||
      l_del_count || ' rows deleted';

   :PX_SUCCESS_MESSAGE := l_success_message;

END;
```

**That would be all, but once again look the tutorial from tip to toe, there's a lot of info that I can't post in here.**

**Disclaimer:** I'm not a skillbuilders representative, I don't own any rights on the video and I'm not promoting skillbuilders web page in any way. I'm just a programmer that found this tutorial useful.

Comment: Actually,My question to retrieve sid,serial# from row(which is corresponding to selected check box) and kill the session by using....        alter system kill session 'sid,serial#' in pl/sql  processes...please give me solution with brief explaination

Comment: That's the solution, if you read it you'll realize that in the fourth step you can do what you want including killing the sessions checked.